# TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python

Есть задачка на https://www.e-olymp.com/ru/problems/7311

> Милхаузу необходимо на завтра решить задачу, и ему нужна Ваша помощь.
>   Вот задача:
>
> Задана строка, состоящая из скобок. Необходимо превратить ее в
>   правильную строку, вставляя как можно меньшее количество скобок в
>   любую позицию (удалять или изменять существующие скобки нельзя).
>   Правильной является строка, которая удовлетворяет следующим правилам:
>
> - Пустая строка правильная.
> - Если s правильная, то (s) также правильная.
> - Если s и t правильные, то их конкатенация st правильная.
>
> Например, "(()())", "" и "(())()" правильные строки, а "())(", "()(" и
>   ")" - нет.
>
> **Входные данные**
>
> Задана строка из скобок, которая содержит от 1 до 50 символов
>   включительно.
>
> **Выходные данные**
>
> Вывести наименьшее количество скобок, которое следует вставить для
>   того чтобы входная строка стала правильной.

Получился такой код:

```
S = input()
a = len(S)
b = 0
c = '('
d = 0
e = 0
f = 0
g = 0

while b < a:
    if a[b] == c:
        e += 1
        b += 1
        break
    else:
        d += 1
        b += 1
        break

f = d - e
g = abs(f)
print(g)
```

А там ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 11, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable.
```

Что делать?

Comment: @Vyrskal, вы пробовали читать правила SO про оформление вопросов? Верните код на место, ссылки на код нарушают правила.

Comment: Не понимаю смысла цикла, если в любом случае после первой итерации будет выход из него. А еще не понимаю зачем переменная `c`, если она служит только константой и то только в одном месте. Да и однобуквенные переменные не есть хорошо -- они не самодокументируемые

Comment: На codewars была подобная задача и я решал ее через стек и после решения ее получил доступ к решениям других людей и там встретился очень простой и интересный алгоритм: https://pastebin.com/mRA1c7iM

Comment: @gil9red, гениальное решение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно задачке нам нужно подсчитать количество незакрытых скобок. Думаю этот способ будет самым простым для данной задачки.

Если строка имеет правильные скобки, то хотя бы в одной итерации цикла найдется пара '()', которую мы удаляем.

После выполнения цикла и удаления всех пар '()' строка будет содержать оставшиеся незакрытые скобки:

```
text = input()
 
while '()' in text:
    text = text.replace('()', '')
 
print(len(text))
```

Answer (score 3):

Вы обращаетесь к переменной с типом `int` как к массиву.

Скорее всего в строке 11 должно быть `if S[b]==c:` вместо `if a[b]==c:`.

Comment: Но, всё-равно на e-olymp выдаёт 10%

Comment: SO это не ресурс для "решите мне задачку". Ищите проблему в логике своего кода, если есть непонятные места - спрашивайте.

Comment: Да я не прошу, а жалуюсь: там даже задача с выводом произведения вышла на 50%, как бы я не пытался (даже циклом)

Comment: Боюсь, что ваше решение не оптимально либо же не учитывает некоторые случаи. Если тестовая система показывает, на каких тестовых данных произошла ошибка, попробуйте посмотреть, какой результат даёт ваш код и сравнить с ожидаемым. А там уже смотреть, что не так.